# Google map marking to fill address automatically using marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to mark my Address(Edit Text) with google map marking.

I have created a simple form but i want to mark it on map when i fill the address and drop a marker on the same place.

I am getting the latitude and longitude for address field then i would pin it using a marker but i have issues at the initial stage only(please consider me as a noob in android since i have started few days back)

**SignUp Activity**

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import butterknife.Bind;
    import butterknife.ButterKnife;

    public class SignupActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, OnInfoWindowCloseListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
        LatLng addressPos;
        Marker addressMarker;

        @Bind(R.id.input_name)
        EditText _nameText;
        @Bind(R.id.input_address)
        EditText _addressText;
        @Bind(R.id.input_email)
        EditText _emailText;
        @Bind(R.id.input_mobile)
        EditText _mobileText;
        @Bind(R.id.input_password)
        EditText _passwordText;
        @Bind(R.id.input_reEnterPassword)
        EditText _reEnterPasswordText;
        @Bind(R.id.btn_signup)
        Button _signupButton;
        @Bind(R.id.link_login)
        TextView _loginLink;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            String address = _addressText.getText().toString();        

            // Initial Map
            try {

                if (googleMap == null) {
                    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       

            _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    signup();
                }
            });

            _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
                }
            });        
        }       

        public void signup() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

            if (!validate()) {
                onSignupFailed();
                return;
            }

            _signupButton.setEnabled(false);

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
                    R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
            progressDialog.show();

            String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
            String address = _addressText.getText().toString();
            String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
            String mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();
            String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
            String reEnterPassword = _reEnterPasswordText.getText().toString();

            // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.

            new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
                            // depending on success
                            onSignupSuccess();
                            // onSignupFailed();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
        }

        public void onSignupSuccess() {
            _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
            finish();
        }

        public void onSignupFailed() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

        public boolean validate() {
            boolean valid = true;

            String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
            String address = _addressText.getText().toString();
            String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
            String mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();
            String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
            String reEnterPassword = _reEnterPasswordText.getText().toString();

            if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
                _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _nameText.setError(null);
            }

            if (address.isEmpty()) {
                _addressText.setError("Enter Valid Address");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _addressText.setError(null);
            }

            if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _emailText.setError(null);
            }

            if (mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length()!=10) {
                _mobileText.setError("Enter Valid Mobile Number");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _mobileText.setError(null);
            }

            if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
                _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _passwordText.setError(null);
            }

            if (reEnterPassword.isEmpty() || reEnterPassword.length() < 4 || reEnterPassword.length() > 10 || !(reEnterPassword.equals(password))) {
                _reEnterPasswordText.setError("Password Do not match");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                _reEnterPasswordText.setError(null);
            }

            return valid;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
            googleMap=Map;
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // Put a dot on my current location
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            // 3D building
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            // Get zoom button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(goodLatLng)
                    .title("Address"));        
        }

        public void showAddressMarker(View view) {

            String newAddress = _addressText.getText().toString();

            if (newAddress != null) {
                new PlaceAMarker().execute(newAddress);
            }
        }
        class PlaceAMarker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String startAddress = params[0];
                startAddress = startAddress.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

                getLatLng(startAddress, false);

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                addressMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(addressPos).title("Address"));
            }
        }
        protected void getLatLng(String address, boolean setDestination) {
            String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                    + address + "&sensor=false";

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

                int byteData;
                while ((byteData = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) byteData);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double lat = 0.0, lng = 0.0;

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                        .getDouble("lng");
                lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                        .getDouble("lat");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               addressPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);        
        }

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClose(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowLongClick(Marker marker) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {        
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {        
        }
    }
```

**Main Activity file**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;        

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }   

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();        
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**signup xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Address Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_address"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/map"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:hint="Address" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- mobile number -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Mobile Number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Re-enter Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_reEnterPassword"
                style="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Re-enter Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Create Account"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the error which i get at runtime nad please specify the thing clearly since i am new to android and keen to learn fast.

**Error Log**

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: package, PID: 6547 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment and so on.
```

Comment: post only necessary code

Comment: Everyone seems to have doubt now and then so i posted my complete problem what i am doing and what is the error still i would take your opinion and try not to do it next time.